# Print each row twice in a 2D array - C

Tags: arrays, c, function, multidimensional-array, printf

Good day! How do I print each row twice in a 2D array in C program?

```
for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[row][col]);            
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The above code is my loop for printing the elements that I received from user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[row][col]);            
    }
    for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[row][col]);            
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

or you want to use only one loop

```cpp
for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 5*2; col++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[row][col%5]);            
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Ah so it was just creating another loop inside a loop. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm so glad that I can help you. Please upvote and accept my answer. If that really helps you. That will help me so much. Thank you.